# CAS integration with node js

Tags: node.js, cas

I want to integrate Central Authorization Server with node JS. I am currently using the node [grand_master_cas](https://github.com/zackrw/grand_master_cas) library. It fetches the login page, but when I enter the username/password, the ticket is displayed in address bar as `local host?ticket=ST-2741-uWij6ecxcLOZyM2nIqfG-cas`. The browser displays the following error:

> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data. Error
> code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? If you know any samples or good posts about the same issue, mention it.

Comment: I have fixed this problem. Instead of giving localhost server provide the server url you want to redirect.                                                               cas.configure({
  casHost: 'secure.its.yale.edu',
  ssl: true,
  service: 'http://google.com',
  redirectUrl: '/splash'
});

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept your answer, if it solves your problem.